# update AppSettings Key value during runtime C#

Tags: c#, sendkeys, appsettings

I am having a problem in sendkeys.send() method which sometimes duplicate some characters `(Ex: "abc123" --> "aabc123")` I googled to find a solution. found that Microsoft recommends change value of `appSettings key="SendKeys"` value to be either "SendInput" OR "JournalHook". I don't want to add extra app.config file BUT I want to make it like 2 radio buttons each of them switch to a certain value of that key and take effect like any normal event. how be that coded?

to make it clear, the question is: if i read the value of "JournalHook" for key="SendKeys" from appsettings section of app.config file, where to set such value in my code?

Comment: The documentation says the only way of setting this is by the AppSettings in the config file. What do you mean by _"I don't want to add extra app.config"_ - doesn't your app have a config file already?

Comment: i am using a stand alone Exe file, and ask for a way to make it programatically inside the Exe

Comment: There isn't a documented way to do it.